# How to use PCL extract a cluster near a point?

Tags: c++, c, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

It is easy to separate a point cloud into several clusters. However, I am looking for a way to extract a cluster that includes a specific point. Is there any function or way to do it? I'd like the answer in C or C++. thx

Comment: Please could you post some code that you have tried?  This really helps others in answering the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, but you can use the [KD-tree search](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php) to retrieve all neighbors of a given point.

You can retrieve your *'cluster'* in two ways:

1. specifying the number of neighbors (**K**) `pcl::KdTree<PointT>::nearestKsearch()`
2. specifying the radius centered in your point of interest `pcl::KdTree<PointT>::radiusSearch()`.

Comment: The theoretical way should be to use your method to put every point to a list Q, and then for every point Q, do the same thing until there's no more points satisfy the radius. However, I'd like to know if there's some function, so that I don't need to traverse Q myself using loops.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way of doing this. However, I am actively working for a second way in order to reduce drastically the computation time.

To do so, when you apply the EuclideanClusterExtraction your code might looks like something like this:

```
std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<pcl::PointXYZ> ec;
ec.setClusterTolerance(0.01);
ec.setMinClusterSize(1);
ec.setMaxClusterSize(subsampled_cloud->size() + 1);
ec.setSearchMethod(tree);
ec.setInputCloud(subsampled_cloud);
ec.extract(cluster_indices);
```

cluster_indices vector is a 2D vector that store points ID by their voxels like this: cluster_indices[voxel ID][point]

From the cluster_indices vector, you can find the point you are looking for by its index using STL vector manipulation like this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr obstacle_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

// Look at each voxel if we find the targeted point, then save the whole voxel
// Here "id_searched_point" is the ID of your point. I can update the code if you don't know the ID
for (std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator i = cluster_indices.begin(); i != cluster_indices.end(); ++i)
{
    if (find(i->indices.begin(), i->indices.end(), id_searched_point) != i->indices.end())
    {
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator pit = i->indices.begin(); pit != i->indices.end(); ++pit)
        {
            obstacle_cloud->points.push_back(subsampled_cloud->points[*pit]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This will extract the voxel you are looking at. Tell me if it does answer your question

EDIT:
Here is the drastically improved solution:

```
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ> octree(10.0f);
octree.setInputCloud(subsampled_cloud);
octree.addPointsFromInputCloud();

pcl::PointXYZ closest;
closest.x = 0;
closest.y = 0;
closest.z = 0;

std::vector<int> pointIdxNKNSearch;
std::vector<float> pointNKNSquaredDistance;

if (octree.nearestKSearch(closest, 1, pointIdxNKNSearch, pointNKNSquaredDistance) <= 0)
{
    std::cout << "No point detected" << std::endl;
    return;
}

// Generate voxel for creating object detection

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr obstacle_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
std::vector<int> pointIdxVec;

if (octree.voxelSearch(subsampled_cloud->points[pointIdxNKNSearch[0]], pointIdxVec) > 0)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < pointIdxVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        obstacle_cloud->points.push_back(subsampled_cloud->points[pointIdxVec[i]]);
    }
}

if (obstacle_cloud->points.size() == 0)
{
    std::cout << "The closest point has not been recorded to any obstacle voxel point" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

I used octree to generate the cluster by the resolution 10.0. This is big so I advise you to change it.
Even I do not consider my previous answer as a solution, but I let it here in case of it can be helpful.